# "Instead of me" in German

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Is there a translation into German for something like:

> Could you answer the phone for me?

Can we use

> Könnten Sie das Telefon anstatt mir beantworten?

Comment: The word _statt_ requires the Genitiv. So, a better translation would be “_Könnten Sie statt meiner den Anruf entgegennehmen?_“ More colloquially, you could say “_Gehst du mal für mich ran?_“ or “_Gehst du mal für mich ans Telefon?_“

Comment: _Könnten Sie statt meiner..._ as a better translation? Only if your target audience is from the 90s... the 1890s ;)

Comment: If your criterium, @hiergiltdiestfu, is how something sounds, you can go on using _statt mir_. I consider correct phrases as better than incorrect ones, and therefore I prefer _statt meiner_ over _statt mir_. The rule is that after _statt_ the Dativ is only allowed when the Genitiv is indistinguishable. I can very well distinguish _meiner_ from _mir_!

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich I'm not picking on any single word, I'm picking on how the whole translation sounds. I would never phrase it like that since it sounds really ancient and highbrow, really. Not sure if that holds for Austria, too, but as a native German, I wouldn't even use that in a professional environment. I personally would always opt for a phrasing based on _für mich_.

Comment: I gave two examples with _für mich_ in my comment.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu In Austria, too, not even schoolteachers would demand _statt meiner_ anymore.

Answer (score 8):

In everyday language you would to the same as in English:

> Könnten Sie das Telefon **für mich** abnehmen.

Also note that currently the word "*anstatt*" is officially used with the genitive but nearly all native speakers will use it with the dative instead - just like you did.

The "official" German grammar differs from the reality in this case.

---

By the way:

"Beantworten" is used for single questions or for any kind of messages that you receive completely and you then write/send/... an answer completely.

Therefore the verb "beantworten" is not used here but one of the following ones:

> das Telefon abnehmen
>
> das Telefon abheben
>
> den Anruf annehmen
>
> den Anruf entgegennehmen

Answer (score 4):

As noted in other answers, you would usually say

> Könnten Sie bitte das Telefon für mich abnehmen.

If you want to sound more formal without using the totally stilted *an meiner statt*, you can also say (or rather, write):

> Könnten Sie bitte das Telefon an meiner Stelle abnehmen.

or

> Könnten Sie bitte das Telefon stellvertetend für mich abnehmen.

Answer (score 3):

> Könnten Sie (bitte) das Telefon **anstatt mir** beantworten?

is okay, but sloppy speech. *Entirely correct* it has to read

> Könnten Sie (bitte) das Telefon **an meiner statt** beantworten?

But nobody actually says that. To weasel out of that awkward phrase, people usually say:

> Könnten Sie (bitte) an mein Telefon gehen?
>
> Könnten Sie (bitte) meine Anrufe entgegennehmen?
>
> Könnten Sie (bitte) meine Anrufe beantworten?

---

To elaborate this a bit more, the problem about this phrase is **anstatt/statt**. This preposition goes with **Genitiv**, but it has a conjuction cognate.

> **Anstatt/Statt** Kuchens hättest du lieber Obst essen sollen. (preposition, *Kuchen* is in genitive because anstatt/statt requires it.)
>
> **Anstatt/Statt** Kuchen zu essen hättest du lieber Obst essen sollen. (Conjunction, *Kuchen* is in accusative because essen requires an accusative object)

There aren't too many prepositions that come with *Genitiv*, and people *always* mix them up, using *Dativ* instead. Anstatt/Statt having another use as a conjunction makes it even easier to get it wrong.

Comment: Ich finde nicht, dass man zum Satz "Könnten Sie bitte das Telefon anstatt mir beantworten" sagen kann, er sei "okay". Er ist im Kontext verständlich, von mir aus. Aber er hat so viele grammatische, stilistische und pragmatische Probleme, dass er wirklich kein gutes Vorbild ist, auch nicht für nachlässige mündliche Kommunikation.

Comment: Wenn du *meiner* statt *mir* einsetzt, ist der Satz grammatisch korrekt und auch verständlich. Besser sind die Beispiele, die ich aufgeschrieben habe.

Comment: > "But nobody actually says that." <- all you need to know about the variations on _anstatt_.

Comment: Nobody says "an meiner statt." My Austrian godmother used to say that.

Comment: *But nobody actually says that.* As written.

Answer (score 0):

Könntest du bitte **an meiner Stelle** ans Telefon gehen?

Könnten Sie bitte **an meiner Stelle** ans Telefon gehen?

Comment: Your answer is a little bit short. It is right and good, but you should add some explanation.